# Laravel App - Admin Route ONLY '/admin' will always return a 404 error | '/admins' or anything else works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, homestead

So if you [go here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/when-routes-url-is-admin-it-results-in-404) you will see the EXACT SAME ISSUE word for word that i'm having...

Basically I have the admin route set like this:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin.app');
});
```

Simple enough right? It always returns this error here:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /admin/ was not found on this server.

If i change the route to `/admins` (plural) or really **anything** else, even `/test` the route displays properly.

I DID have an admin folder inside my public folder, but I have since deleted the admin folder and now the problem is still persisting. I don't really understand why. I'm running on a Laravel/Homestead environment. Basic LEMP stack. Nothing special.

Edit: When i type in mysite.dev:8000/admin it directs me automatically to mysite.dev/admin (Notice there is no port) So, now i'm really even more confused. :/

Edit 2: Changed the route to `admin/dashboard` works just fine. Could it be possible that Laravel has defined the `/admin` route as a 'reserved route' or something (similar to reserved keywords in any programming language) to where it won't ever display anything? Is that even a thing?

```
Route::get('admin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('admin.app');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: don't name your folder as ADMIN if you have /admin in ur URLs. rename the folder to some other name.

Answer (score 1):

delete or rename admin folder in public and run

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have admin name folder in your public directory if you remove that it will work [enter link description here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/when-routes-url-is-admin-it-results-in-404)